# Rest Generic does not work properly in jax-rs

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Good morning.

I have a problem with the answers of rest services that use generics - I have a generic object that has the following structure:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Data implements Serializable {
    private Object data;
    private Long numero_reg;

    /**
     * @return the data
     */
    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numero_reg
     */
    public long getNumero_reg() {
        return numero_reg;
    }

    /**
     * @param numero_reg the numero_reg to set
     */
    public void setNumero_reg(long numero_reg) {
        this.numero_reg = numero_reg;
    }

}
```

When answer a rest one to object to the objects that meet the different rest with the purpose of standardized response follows:

```
@Path("/pruebas")
public class Pruebita {
    @GET
    public Data getalgo(){
        ObjectoDatos od=new ObjectoDatos();
        od.setPrueba("hola");
        od.setPrueba2("hola2");
        Data sd=new Data();
        sd.setData(od);
        sd.setNumero_reg(1);
        return sd;
    }
}
```

When it meets the response json answer it becomes a toString of the object and is not showing the data of the object.
Can someone help me?

```
{"data":"bo.ObjectoDatos@6d858b63","numero_reg":1}
```

This is the error - I got to the toString of the object , and not the object itself.

Comment: Did you override the toString method of your Documentos class? What is there in this class?

Comment: Did you add the Documentos class to the ObjectMapper?

Comment: Yes is tostring method is override jpa entity but i tried too, with Java pojo without override tostring method in The genéric i got "bo.bl.Documentos@2213abc"

Comment: Objectmapper??  When?

Comment: Please show how the code where you're using ObjectMapper.

Comment: I dont use objectmapper you have any example??

Comment: hello any maybe help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution -
I use the HashMaps class from guava repackaged :

```
    @Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
    int response = responseContext.getStatus();
    Object entidad = responseContext.getEntity();
    if (entidad != null && response == 200) {
        int nroRegistros = (entidad instanceof List) ? (((List) entidad).size()) : 1;
        Map<String, Object> respuesta = Maps.newHashMap();
        respuesta.put("data", entidad);
        if(nroRegistros != 1) {
            respuesta.put("numero_reg", nroRegistros);                
        }
        responseContext.setEntity(respuesta);
    }
}
```

The above code works well and solves my issues.